# Installing Couchbase with helm chart fails with Readiness probe

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, couchbase

I've just migrated to M1 Macbook and tried to deploy couchbase using Couchbase Helm Chart on Kubernetes. https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/current/helm-setup-guide.html

But, couchbase server pod fails with message below

> Readiness probe failed: dial tcp 172.17.0.7:8091: connect: connection
> refused

Pod uses image: couchbase/server:7.0.2

Error from log file:

```
Starting Couchbase Server -- Web UI available at http://<ip>:8091
and logs available in /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs
runtime: failed to create new OS thread (have 2 already; errno=22)
fatal error: newosproc
runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x4d8d66, 0x9)
/home/couchbase/.cbdepscache/exploded/x86_64/go-1.8.5/go/src/runtime/panic.go:596 +0x95
runtime.newosproc(0xc420028000, 0xc420038000)
/home/couchbase/.cbdepscache/exploded/x86_64/go-1.8.5/go/src/runtime/os_linux.go:163 +0x18c
runtime.newm(0x4df870, 0x0)
/home/couchbase/.cbdepscache/exploded/x86_64/go-1.8.5/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1628 +0x137
runtime.main.func1()
/home/couchbase/.cbdepscache/exploded/x86_64/go-1.8.5/go/src/runtime/proc.go:126 +0x36
runtime.systemstack(0x552700)
/home/couchbase/.cbdepscache/exploded/x86_64/go-1.8.5/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:327 +0x79
runtime.mstart()
/home/couchbase/.cbdepscache/exploded/x86_64/go-1.8.5/go/src/runtime/proc.go:1132
goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.systemstack_switch()
/home/couchbase/.cbdepscache/exploded/x86_64/go-1.8.5/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:281 fp=0xc420024788 sp=0xc420024780
runtime.main()
/home/couchbase/.cbdepscache/exploded/x86_64/go-1.8.5/go/src/runtime/proc.go:127 +0x6c fp=0xc4200247e0 sp=0xc420024788
runtime.goexit()
/home/couchbase/.cbdepscache/exploded/x86_64/go-1.8.5/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2197 +0x1 fp=0xc4200247e8 sp=0xc4200247e0
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,encryption_service,{port_terminated,normal}}},{ns_babysitter,start,[normal,[]]}}}},[{ns_babysitter_bootstrap,start,0,[{file,"src/ns_babysitter_bootstrap.erl"},{line,23}]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ({{badmatch,{error,{{_},{_}}}},[{ns_babysitter_bootstrap,start,0,[{_},{_}]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Couchbase Server 7.1.1 is the first version whose Docker images are multi-platform with support for M1 chips. Does using that version resolve the issue?

Comment: Thanks @dnault. I changed the Couchbase Server version to 7.1.1  and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems ARM64 version of Couchbase Server for MacOS has become available since Couchbase Server 7.1.1.

So, I ran the command below to install couchbase.

```
helm install couchbasev1 --values myvalues.yaml couchbase/couchbase-operator
```

myvalues.yaml:

```
cluster:
  image: couchbase/server:7.1.1
```

And it worked.